# How to manage huge data in machine learning with AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am relatively new to Tensorflow and machine learning. I have a dataset running into million rows with >2000 columns each. I am thinking of using Tensorflow on AWS AMI (C5 Instance). I am not sure about where/ how to store this huge data.

1- Should I be storing this as csv in S3 bucket or should I load this in some bigdata system and then use Apache spark for streaming it out? Can you please guide me here.

2- Also, if I have to clean this data, what would be the right approach? Maybe use AWS Sagemaker and use python/ pandas (via notebook) to clean the data? Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give some advices but every project is different and use what works best for you.

Is it a one timer data exploration or something you need to crunch on a frequent schedule?  In order to do it frequently, spark might be the right tool. Spark is awesome at transforming/featurizing/cleaning/preprocessing your data into something more usable for tensorflow (usually into sparse format). The important thing here is to keep your gpus busy and to achieve that, you need to preprocess as much as you can before using tf. S3 is a good storage if you do not have small files.

For tensorflow to be happy, most of the time you need to densify your feature vectors. By that, you take a minibatch of records and transform sparse feature vectors into dense vectors. Only then you can send it to tf. This is because gpus are pretty bad at working with sparse data and some operations like convolutions do not even support sparse inputs. (all that can change anytime since it is an active field of research)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. It helps a lot. What I may need is a one time exploration, basically to arrive at the most relevant columns and to cleanse the data. For this specific case, as I understand, the best approach will be to first load/ clean/ transform the data in Apache Spark and use that cleansed data in Tensorflow. Did I understand you right?

Comment: Exactly..  however, if you do it only once, you might as well use regular python or other tools you are familiar with.